# Selecting the version of puppet client during installation -Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, puppet

I am trying to install puppet agent in a ubuntu machine.

When I run this command ,sudo apt-get install puppet
the latest version gets installed which is 3.4.2 . I want to instal the previous versions of puppet. is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to see if you have other version available by using the following commend:

```
apt-cache showpkg puppet
```

The output should give something like (real output shows many more versions):

```
3.4.2-1puppetlabs1 -
3.2.4-1puppetlabs1 -
3.1.1-1puppetlabs1 -
3.0.2-1puppetlabs1 -
2.7.25-1puppetlabs1 -
```

Then you can install the version you need with:

```
apt-get install puppet=2.7.25-1puppetlabs1
```

Hope this helps.